# How to add favicon to javadoc gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

How to add custom favicon to javadoc built using gradle?

```
javadoc {
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    classpath = configurations.compileClasspath
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    // currently our javadoc has a lot of errors, so we need to suppress the linter
    options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
}

task releaseJavadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    title = project.name + ' ' + project.property('version')
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    classpath = configurations.compileClasspath
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    // currently our javadoc has a lot of errors, so we need to suppress the linter
    options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
}
```

Above is code for buidling javadocs.

[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKo8n.png)

Want to replace this with custom favicon.